# Data isn't being saved in the text file (C++ Fstream library )

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I've been trying to save the score of the player in the game in a text file, but it doesn't do so.
This is the code I'm using:

```
//some code above 

std::fstream TextScore ("Ranking.txt");


// some code above

if (Player->getFinal(Map) == true)
    {
        TextScore.open("Ranking.txt", ios::out);
        TextScore << Player->getPoints();
        TextScore.close();
        //some code below
    }
```

Then I check the text file and nothing has been saved, the file is empty.
I would like to know what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that statement even executes (i.e. that the `if`'s condition is ever satisfied)?

Comment: It compiles, but the text file remains empty, which means that the score is not being saved in the text file.

Comment: Yes, it is satisfied.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right file? Are you sure it opened successfully?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking in the right file.

Comment: Can you `cassert (TextScore.is_open())` to confirm your are succeeding in opening Ranking.txt?

Comment: _"Yes, it is satisfied."_ _"Yes. I'm looking in the right file."_ Prove it! You're missing something. How do we know it's not one of those two things?

Answer (score 3):

```
std::fstream TextScore ("Ranking.txt");
```

This opens the file, as if `TextScore.open("Ranking.txt"), std::ios::in|std::ios::out)` was called.

```
TextScore.open("Ranking.txt", std::ios::out);
```

This opens it again.

The combination is not going to work if the file already exists. The first open will succeed and the second one will fail. After that, all I/O operations will fail. Open it just once, either in the constructor or in a separate `open` call. The most idiomatic C++ way would be

```
{
  std::fstream TextScore ("Ranking.txt", std::ios::out);
  TextScore << Player->getPoints();
}
```

No need to close the file explicitly thanks to RAII.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but now it overwrites the scores.

Comment: Sure it does. What would you expect?

Comment: Perhaps try adding `std::ios::ate`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Scores are still being overwritten, it only appears the last one saved.

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: Use `std::ios::out | std::ios::app` to append to a file without truncating.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the same file twice is certainly going to cause problems. Move the definition of `TextScore` into the body of the `if` statement in place of the call to `TextScore.open()`. And then you can remove the call to `TextScore.close()`; the destructor will close the file.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, the scores are being overwritten so that it only appears the last score saved. How  can I fix that?